# TemporalAdjuster - getting next date from adjusted date

Tags: java, date, java-time, localdate, temporal

Assuming I have a custom `TemporalAdjuster` that gives me every Sunday (could also be every second Tuesday etc..). How can I calculate **all** the adjusted dates in a year?

```
TemporalAdjuster myGamingAdjuster;
int myYear = 2003;
LocalDate myDate = LocalDate.now();
System.out.println(myDate.with(myGamingAdjuster)); // Gives only one date
```

Comment: can you please explain with simple input and output example

Comment: for example :I have a custom TemporalAdjuster.I don't know exactly what he does. It could be that this adjuster gives me a Sunday (about 52 times a year) or Christmas (once a year). Now, I want a loop to find all occurring dates in a time span. For example all appointments with this custom adjuster in one year.

Comment: Are you sure that a `TemporalAdjuster` is the right representation for your repetition scheme? I haven’t really understood how it’s supposed to do what you want it to do.

Comment: Not all `TemporalAdjuster` implementations increment to future dates. Some, such as `firstDayOfYear()` and [`firstDayOfMonth()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#firstDayOfMonth()) will repeatedly return the same value. In other words, some `TemporalAdjuster` objects are [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence).

Comment: Also not all `TemporalAdjuster`s restrict themselves to the year. For example `TemporalAdjusters.previous(DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY)` may adjust a date into the previous year. To have it adjust to the last Wednesday of 2003 (which was December 31 that year), you would need to start from a date in 2004. I think you are asking the impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom method, which generate what you expect, from the two needs in your question, You can create a method like this:

```
public List<LocalDate> generateDates(int year, int periodicDays, DayOfWeek startDay){
    LocalDate firstDay = LocalDate.of(year, Month.JANUARY, 1)
            .with(TemporalAdjusters.next(startDay));
    List<LocalDate> result = new ArrayList<>();
    do {
        result.add(firstDay);
        firstDay = firstDay.plusDays(periodicDays);
    } while (firstDay.getYear() == year);
    return result;
}
```

Then, call your method like so:

```
List<LocalDate> allSunDaysInYear = generateDates(2003, 7, DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)
List<LocalDate> allEvrySeconTuesdaysInYear = generateDates(2003, 14, DayOfWeek.MONDAY);
```

**Outputs**

```
[2003-01-05, 2003-01-12, 2003-01-19, 2003-01-26, 2003-02-02, 2003-02-09, ..]
[2003-01-06, 2003-01-20, 2003-02-03, 2003-02-17, 2003-03-03, 2003-03-17, ..]
```

Comment: thanks, this does help me alot man! <3 but how do i handle adjusters, which are e.g just once a year? for example christmas? because i dont know the "content" of the adjuster

Comment: @Zeraki it depends on your action, for that, I would like to create a method for each case, because each case can be different of the others, there are no one solution for all problems.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the 'GamingAdjuster' tells you the next date when you may switch on your PlayStation, based on the last date you used it? We assume that this last date is now …

Unfortunately, you have no clue if that adjuster will just add an hour, or whether it will adjust the start date always to next the reachable Christmas Eve, right?

Nevertheless, you would like to know how many game sessions you can have for the remainder of this year, correct?

Try something like this:

```
var currentYear = Year.now();
var startDate = LocalDateTime.now();
var counter = 0;

for( var date = startDate.with( myGamingAdjuster ); date.getYear() == currentYear.getValue(); date = date.with( myGamingAdjuster ) )
{
    ++counter;
}

out.println( counter );
```

I use `LocalDateTime` because in my assumption, the adjuster could also add one hour – that would not work for `LocalDate`. And if you have really *no* clue on how the adjuster works, this would be the safer option.

We have to initialise `date` in the way I did to avoid that *now* is counted, too, because we only want to count the still possible game sessions, and the current one is over …